# Сортировка слиянием двух массивов

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка, сортировка-слиянием

Программа должна выполнить сортировку слиянием массива городов по массиву чисел(людей в нём проживающих).
Проблема с алгоритмом сортировки слиянием.
Прошу помочь исправить ошибку в коде.

Результат выполнения программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Размер массива
#define size 9

/*cityName - массив указателей на константные строки.
В нём можно менять местами указатели, но сами строки изменять нельзя.*/ 
char *cityName[size] = {"Moscow","New-York","London","Minsk","Kiev","Warsaw","Berlin","Tokio","Hong-Kong"};
int urbanPopulation[size] = {12330126, 8400000, 8500000, 1836808, 2893000, 1700536, 3950887, 13370198, 7071576};

void arrayCity(int *array1, char **array2);
void swapArray(int *array1, char **array2);

int main (void) {
  arrayCity(urbanPopulation, cityName);
  swapArray(urbanPopulation, cityName);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("In %-10s %s %-9d peoples\n", cityName[i],"lives", urbanPopulation[i]);
  return 0;
}

void arrayCity(int *array1, char **array2) {
  printf("\r\n[-]Unsorted Urban Population:\r\n");
  printf("=====================================\r\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("In %-10s %s %-9d peoples\r\n", array2[i], "lives", array1[i]);
}
void swapArray(int *array1, char **array2) {
  printf("\r\n\r\n[+] Sorted Urban Population:\r\n");
  printf("=====================================\r\n");
  int mid = size / 2; // находим середину массива
  if (size % 2 == 1)
    mid++;
  int h = 1;   // шаг
  int i = 0;   // индекс первого пути
  int j = mid; // индекс второго пути
  int k = 0;   // индекс элемента в результирующей последовательности
  int *temp_a = malloc(size * sizeof *temp_a); // выделение памяти
  char **temp_b = malloc(size * sizeof *temp_b);
  int step;
  while(h < size) {
    step = h;
    while (step <= mid) {
      while ((i < step) && (j < size) && (j < (mid + step))) {
        /*пока не дошли до конца пути
        заполняем следующий элемент формируемой последовательности
        меньшим из двух просматриваемых*/
        if (array1[i] < array1[j]) {
          temp_a[k] = array1[i];
          temp_b[k] = array2[i];
          i++; k++;
        }
        else {
          temp_a[k] = array1[j];
          temp_b[k] = array2[j];
          j++; k++;
        }
      }
      while(i < step) { // переписываем оставшиеся элементы первого пути (если второй кончился раньше)
        temp_a[k] = array1[i];
        temp_b[k] = array2[i];
        i++; k++;
      }
      while((j < (mid + step)) && (j < size)) {  // переписываем оставшиеся элементы второго пути (если первый кончился раньше)
        temp_a[k] = array1[j];
        temp_b[k] = array2[j];
        j++; k++;
      }
      step = step + h; // переходим к следующему этапу
    }
    h *= 2;
    // Переносим упорядоченную последовательность (промежуточный вариант) в исходный массив
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      array1[i] = temp_a[i];
      array2[i] = temp_b[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ветке else первого if идет копирование из индекса j, а инкремент почему-то для i.

Далее - код выполняет один проход-слияние, образуя 4 упорядоченных пары из элементов первой и второй половины. После этого i,j дошли до конца, и всё.

Подозреваю, что имелся в виду такой алгоритм слияния - на первом шаге сливаются элементы 0 + 1, 2 + 3 и т.д. На втором шаге - 0,1 + 2,3, 4,5 + 6,7 и т.д., пока длина сливаемых кусков не превысит длину массива.

Comment: Благодарю и вправду стало лучше, но алгоритм по прежнему не сортирует. Я использовал GDB но он ведь не выдаёт ошибки, код ведь компилируется. Проблема в логике алгоритма. Изменил результат в вопросе.

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Answer (score 0):

Благодарю за помощь!
Разобрался с алгоритмом и синтаксисом. Я выбрал не тот алгоритм слияния, вместо нисходящего делал двух-путевым.
Выкладываю код может кому-то пригодится.

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define size 9

char *cityName[size] = {"Moscow","New-York","London","Minsk","Kiev","Warsaw","Berlin","Tokio","Hong-Kong"};
int urbanPopulation[size] = {12330126, 8400000, 8500000, 1836808, 2893000, 1700536, 3950887, 13370198, 7071576};

void arrayCity(int *array1, char **array2);
void merge_sort(int *array1, char **array2, int l, int r);

int main(void) {
  arrayCity(urbanPopulation, cityName);
  merge_sort(urbanPopulation, cityName, 0, size - 1); // вызываем функцию сортировки
  printf("\n");
  // Выводим отсортированные массивы
  printf("\r\n\r\n[+] Sorted Urban Population:\r\n");
  printf("=====================================\r\n");
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("In %-10s %s %-9d peoples\n", cityName[i],"lives", urbanPopulation[i]);
  return 0;
}

// Функция выводит несортированную таблицу городов и людей там проживающих.
void arrayCity(int *array1, char **array2) {
  printf("\r\n[-]Unsorted Urban Population:\r\n");
  printf("=====================================\r\n");  
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("In %-10s %s %-9d peoples\r\n", array2[i], "lives", array1[i]);
}

// Функция сортировки нисходящим слиянием
void merge_sort(int *array1, char **array2, int l, int r) {

  if (l == r)
    return; // границы сомкнулись массив отсортирован.
  int mid = (l + r) / 2; // определяем середину последовательности
  // и рекурсивно вызываем функцию сортировки для каждой половины

  merge_sort(array1, array2, l, mid);
  merge_sort(array1, array2, mid + 1, r);

  int i = l;  // начало первого пути
  int j = mid + 1; // начало второго пути

  int *temp_a = malloc(size * sizeof *temp_a); // дополнительный массив чисел
  char **temp_b = malloc(size * sizeof *temp_b); // дополнительный массив строк

  for(int step = 0; step < r - l + 1; step++) {
    // для всех элементов дополнительного массива
    // записываем в формируемую последовательность меньший из элементов двух путей
    // или остаток первого пути если j > r
    if ((j > r) || ((i <= mid) && (array1[i] < array1[j]))) {
      temp_a[step] = array1[i];
      temp_b[step] = array2[i];
      i++;
    }
    else {
      temp_a[step] = array1[j];
      temp_b[step] = array2[j];
      j++;
    }
  }
  // переписываем сформированную последовательность в исходный массив
  for (int step = 0; step < r - l + 1; step++) {
    array1[l + step] = temp_a[step];
    array2[l + step] = temp_b[step];
  }
}
```